# <a> tags using CSS background images have no text

Tags: css, anchor, background-image

I have  tags and submit buttons on a website that were built using background images that included the words Submit, Go, etc. If images are disabled then the buttons completely disappear. The specifications when building the website were quite detailed and strict.

- They like a mouse-over effect when hovering over buttons. This is
  accomplished with image sprites as background images and the hover
  selector.
- They purchased a special font to be used in the graphics that is not
  a web standard font.
- They like the drop shadow on the text in the graphics and all of the
  buttons have white text.
- They like rounded corners on their buttons so all background images
  have transparent corners because some pages are white and some forms
  have a yellow background.

One solution I thought of where they would not have to give up anything is to put a 1 pixel transparent gif in an img tag in the anchor tag and put the "Go" or "Submit" text in the alt attribute. Is that acceptable, especially for SEO purposes?

The other method just leads to a chain of changes I'd rather not do, but will if I have to.
Keep the background image but move the text to the anchor link and use a standard web font. But since this would still be white text on a white page and not visible, I'd have to assign a dark background color. But since this would appear behind the transparent corners of the images, I'll have to make up multiple versions of the same buttons with different background colors for the white and yellow page/forms.

Or is there something else that I haven't thought of?

Comment: So, you want default text if your CSS fails to load?

Comment: Yes, I'd like some text to show up if images are disabled or if the CSS fails to load.

Comment: If you are using hard coded `<img>` set your `alt` attributes for if the image fails to load. If you are using CSS to add images to a background, you can add the text into the element and use `text-indent:-9999px;` to move it off the screen. When CSS isn't loaded the image will be placed normal.

Comment: if you need only the image to be loaded, then you must go for `<div>` and then go for the css ruling. You must not be worrying about the SEO thing, because it won't do any good to you unless you do it manually(you can't expect your page to be crawled only because your code is good!).
And, if you want to use a fallback text for the buttons, you must go for Javascript. [This](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-javascript-fallback-methods/) must help.

Answer (score 0):

From a general DOM spec, there is no mandatory requirements for `<a>` tags to have a text; they can have, for e.g., an image (`<img>` element) that may serve as a 'clickable' link.

Answer (score 0):

Explain to your client that using images for buttons isn't best practice. Intsead, use CSS3 to generate the buttons- Better performance and easier to maintain. As for the custom font they use, check to see if there's an option to license use for @font-face. If not, I'm sure there's a similar font out there.

Comment: They aren't satisfied with the looks of CSS generated buttons.

Comment: Now I'm curious to know what the buttons look like. Could you post one?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily enough with "image replacement" techniques, where an image is placed over the original text. The original text shows in place of the images if images are disabled or if they don't load. It's a little tricky if the images are transparent, but it can be done. Here's a simple example with a button element, but it can be done on most elements:

http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-16469524-sprite/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
body {background: #e7e7e7;}

button {
    position: relative; 
    width: 150px;
    height:40px;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #27485b;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

button:hover {background: #bd9755;}

button span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-16469524-sprite/bg.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

button:hover span {background-position: 0 -40px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<button value="Send" name="submit" type="submit">Submit<span></span></button>

</body>
</html>
```